# How To Change Button Color, But Keep Icon

Tags: google-app-maker

So I know how to change the color of a button using

```
.app-Button--Blue {
  color: #0277BD;
}
```

However this only lets me change the color of the button when it's in text mode. Is there a way I can have it change the color of the button?

Current using this for dropdowns and it works perfectly. Just want to do the same thing with the buttons in "icon mode".

```
.app-Dropdown--Custom .app-Dropdown-Arrow:after {
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to compose variants, so your options are:

1. Add styles to each specific button, e.g.

```css
.app-NewPage1-Button1,
.app-NewPage1-Button2 {
  color: green;
}
```

2. Define a class and assign it to each icon button you want to style

```css
.greenButton {
  color: green;
}
```

3. Define a new variant that makes the button use the icon font and
   sets the color:

```css
.app-Button--GreenIcon {
  color: green;
  font-family: "Material Icons Extended";
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I used the 3rd option and it did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to extend default AM style variant. I'm not aware if there is a beautiful way achieve it... From the top of my head I can suggest some approaches:

**First:**

1. Apply Icon button variant to all buttons you want
2. Write custom CSS to color each button instance

```css
.app-PageA-ButtonX,
.app-PageB-ButtonY,
.....
{
  color: green;
}
```

**Second:**

1. Implement your custom icon button variant:

```css
.app-Button--CustomIcon {
  color: green;
}
```

2. Add default AM button variant to the button style list (for each button you want):
   [image]